# Span of a subspace, with Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

I need some help, I haven't learned anything in Linear my professor's teaching style just doesn't work for me. So i have no examples to work off of on how to do this problem.

I have the following polynomials

1. $p_1(t)=1+t$
2. $p_2(t)=1-t$
3. $p_3(t)=4$
4. $p_4(t)=t+t^2$
5. $p_5(t)=1+2t+t^2$

Let $K = \text{Span}\{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,p_5\}$ a sub-space of $P^2$

How can I determine what polynomials can be removed without changing $K$?

Comment: 1. I’ve edited to put your post into proper MathJax, and hope that I have not misinterpreted your intent. In particular, I don’t know whether that should have been $P_2$ instead of $P^2$. And I presume that “P2” meant the polynomials of degree at most two? 2. You should learn basic TeX/MathJax if you intend to post again.

Comment: you are correct the polynomials of degree two

Comment: Hint: a good start would be to determine the dimension of $K$.  It is clearly at least $1$ and at most $5$.  Can you compute it exactly?

Comment: Hmmm I think I get it so If i set the Polynomials up in a matrix and row reduce I have 3 pivot columns so the dim(K)=3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Write the given polynomials as vectors with respect to the basis $1,t,t^2$. Put them as rows in a $5 \times 3$ matrix and use row reduction.

Comment: Ok so after doing that and row reducing I see that I can get rid of P3(t)=4 && P5(t) = 1+2t+t^2   right?

Comment: @user203042, that's one solution, yes.

Comment: Okay so i'm a bit confused still If I remove those two polynomials because I still have a set of Linear independent vectors that span P3? and therefore span the subspace?

Comment: @user203042, if you get a row-reduced matrix of rank $3$ then the vectors span the whole space.

Comment: Ah okay, we haven't learned about rank yet unfortunately.. So i'm trying to say it in terms that would make sense for the beggining of the course

Comment: @user203042, rank $3$ is the same as exactly $2$ zero rows.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:** 
You can express the polynomials $1,t$ and $t^2$ by linear combinations of the given polynomials. $\ (1)$
(Therefore, you can express *all* at most quadratic polynomials.) 
We can remove an item from our list till as long the remaining ones satisfy $(1)$.